# Instantiating an nmos inside an interface (UVM)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, modelsim, uvm

I've got an interface in my UVM testbench, that consists of multiple nmos instantiations. The simulator(modelsim) complains about this as it is an LRM violation (cannot have instantiations of anything other than an interface, inside an interface). I need to move the instantiations outside of the interface.

How do I do it? Can it be done via modport or tasks? This is legacy code that I did not write.

```
interface model_interface(input wire mac_clk,input reset);
    
    wire  [31:0] modelio_vi;
     
    wire  [31:0] modelio_data_in;
    wire  [31:0] modelio_data_out;
    wire  [31:0] modelio_data_oen;
    logic [4:0]                  modelio_mode_if [32];
    logic [4:0]                  ulp_modelio_mode_if [32];
    logic                        sample_if [32];  

    bit                          ulp_modelio_mux_en;
    bit                          host_disable;

    genvar loop;
    //The below block is the issue
    generate
        for(loop=0; loop<32; loop=loop+1)
        begin:asgn
           nmos inst_1(modelio_vi[loop],  modelio_data_in[loop], (~modelio_data_oen[loop]));//TB to DUT Buffer
           nmos inst_2(modelio_data_out[loop], modelio_vi[loop], ( modelio_data_oen[loop]));//DUT to TB Buffer
        end
    endgenerate
endinterface
```

Answer (score 1):

`nmos` has to be instantiated inside a module as it is a Verilog switch primitive.

`nmos (out,in,ctrl);` is functionally the same as `assign out = ctrl ? in : 'z;`, so you could just switch to using assign statements for minimal code change. Othersize you must move your `nmos` into a separate module and assign connect the shared signals.

```
generate
    for(loop=0; loop<32; loop=loop+1)
    begin:asgn
       assign modelio_vi[loop] =  !modelio_data_oen[loop] ? modelio_data_in[loop] : 'z;//TB to DUT Buffer
       assign modelio_data_out[loop] = modelio_data_oen[loop] ? modelio_vi[loop] : 'z;//DUT to TB Buffer
    end
endgenerate
```

Comment: nmos is needed if you need to pass strengths through.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. While, this does resolve the LRM issue, it creates functional errors during simulation. The original intent was to have this signal driven from the DUT and the TB, and whichever is the higher strength, will go through. So, the nmos would still be necessary.